# Javascript contentEditable of certain classes only

Tags: javascript, contenteditable

I have the following script that makes an HTML page editable

```
document.body.contentEditable = 'true'; document.designMode='on';
```

I am wanting to only allow my users to edit sections with a class of "edit". Is this possible?

Comment: @IslamElshobokshy who said he didnt already try to do it himself?

Comment: @Luke_ you need to provide the code you've tried, if none is provided one assumes he didn't try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

YOu can try to find all the elements with the class name 'edit' and change all off them like below.

```
document.querySelectorAll('.edit').forEach(function(element){
    element.contentEditable = 'true';
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes that's possbile.

```
let el_array = document.getElementsByClassName('edit');
```

Then loop on el_array and apply this to each element `el.contentEditable = true;`

---

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is possible, just run a simple loop over all elements with the edit class and give them contentEditable true

```
[...document.getElementsByClassName("edit")].forEach(
  el => el.contentEditable = "true"
);
```

Thats all!

Edit: as harry mentioned in the comments: forEach doesnt work on htmlCollection objects, so you must cast it to an array using [...theHTMLCollection]

Comment: *forEach* does not apply to *getElementsByClassName*

Comment: Ah yes, i forgot about that, corrected!

Answer (score 1):

```js
function edit_content(){
  document.querySelectorAll('.myP').forEach(function(ele){
      ele.contentEditable = 'true';
  })
}
```

```html
<p class="myP">
abcdefghijklmnop
</p>

<button onclick="edit_content()">
Click to edit
</button>
```

you can do this. first, select all classes in the DOM by `querySelectorAll` then iterate that from `forEach` loop.