# contentEditable by class = false not working

Tags: javascript, dom, contenteditable

I have a button that calls a function when clicked that makes all items with a class editable. It works great. The issue I am having, is I need to remove `contentEditable="true"` or set it to false because when the user is done editing, the page is exported.

**Code to enable editing (works)**

```
function editMode(){
    document.querySelectorAll('.edit').forEach(function(element){
        element.contentEditable = 'true';
    })
}
```

**Code that does not work as expected:**

```
function editOff(){
    document.querySelectorAll('.edit').forEach(function(element){
        element.contentEditable = 'false';
    })
}
```

The elements with the "edit" class continue to be editable. When the function `editOff` is called, they should not be editable any longer.

Reference to above script: [Javascript contentEditable of certain classes only [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64389650/javascript-contenteditable-of-certain-classes-only)

Comment: What in particular is not working? Do the elements continue to be content-editable after you set `contentEditable = 'false'`?

Comment: @Camelid That is correct, and I have edited the question to reflect that.

Comment: does the user click another button to finish editing?

Comment: @Dr.Tenma Yes. The user would click a button with a onclick="editOff()"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work for you?

Source: source code is from the reference in your question.

```js
function editMode(){
    document.querySelectorAll('.edit').forEach(function(element){
        element.contentEditable = 'true';
    })
}

function editOff(){
    document.querySelectorAll('.edit').forEach(function(element){
        element.contentEditable = 'false';
    })
}
```

```html
<p class="edit">
abcdefghijklmnop
</p>

<button onclick="editMode()">
Click to edit
</button>

<button onclick="editOff()">
Click to stop edit
</button>
```

Comment: Yes! It works perfectly. I am trying to expand my JS knowledge. What went wrong in my code included in the question?

Comment: To be honest, there was nothing wrong with your code. Check my updated snippet where I've used your functions. - Maybe you forget to set class="edit" on your elements?